# Solr not returning the exact element

Tags: solr

Using Solr 7.7.3
I have an element with the label:"alpha-ravi"
and when I search in solr label:"alpha" its returning the element with the label "alpha-ravi"
when looking at the solr doc, it should not return this element.
can anyone explain why this behavior ?
[image]

Comment: That will depend on the analysis chain of the field in question; the default tokenizer for a text field will split the tokens at `-` as well, so if you don't want that behavior, change the field type to a different field type with the behavior you want and reindex. If you only want _exact_ matches, use `string` - if you only want to tokenize on whitespace, use a `WhitespaceTokenizer` instead of the StandardTokenizer (or others)

Comment: @MatsLindh Sorry am new to solr, Didnt quite get what you said. Is there any example/reference to what you said ? I am looking at doc but am lost.

Comment: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/understanding-analyzers-tokenizers-and-filters.html

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks got some idea about it . ^^ Looks complicated though.

Comment: If you only want exact matches, define the field as a string. If you want to tokenize it on white space, use an analysis chain with a Whitespacetokenizer and then a lowercase filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the exact results (i.e return docs with "alpha-ravi" only if the user types the exact "alpha-ravi" in the search), then I would suggest you could go with the Keyword tokenizer (solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory). This tokenizer would treat the entire "alpha-ravi" as a single token and thus, will not return partial results if there's a match for "alpha" or "ravi".

For example: in your schema.xml file you should add something like (configure the various filter chains as per your need)

```
 <fieldType name="single_token_string" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

And then you can use this fieldType in the same schema.xml (referencing the KeywordTokenizer we just defined)

```
<field name="myField" type="single_token_string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

By default, Solr uses the StandardTokenizer and thus, splits "alpha-ravi" on that hyphen into multiple tokens (thus, matching "alpha" and "ravi").

Also, as an alternative you could run a query with a phrase as well (which will not be tokenized on spaces/delimiters). Possibly something like`http:localhost:8983/solr/...fq=label:"alpha-ravi"`

Hope that helps. All the best!

Comment: Thanks @yuniktmr Finally managed to tackle the issue. What I did is made a new field_type adjust the tokenizer with my preferences and used that field type for my query. Thanks Everyone.